# Creating List/Vector from a String

Tags: r

From a data frame I am reading a column that contains medical device submission numbers. Ideally only 1 number should be associated with a medical device. However, in some instances there are medical devices with multiple numbers. I want to create a list of multiple numbers.

so right now, when I loop around a data frame (deviceRecallsReports) column "k_numbers", I get the following output:

```
[1] "K020386"

[1] "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"

[1] "K082829"

[1] "K043520"

[1] "c(\"K040738\", \"K061414\")"

[1] "K080391"

[1] "K991569"

[1] "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"

[1] "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"

[1] "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"

[1] "K063454"

[1] "K053240"

[1] "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"

[1] "K043520"

[1] "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"

[1] "K141967"

[1] "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"

[1] "K991569"

[1] "K013931"


for (row in 1:nrow(deviceRecallsReports)) 
{
               knum <- deviceRecallsReports[row, "k_numbers"]
               print(paste(knum))
}
```

The rows with just one number such as "K020386" or "K991569" are fine. But for the rest of the rows which are multiple numbers in a supposed list "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")", I want to create an actual R vector or list out of. so I want a vector/list that would be:
 ("K032509", "K093308", "K082566").

I am not sure how to strip or unlist this right now.

Comment: What is the class of that column in R?  Can you apply `sapply(data,class)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If `deviceCallreports` is an ordinary data.frame, and your column `k_numbers` an ordinary character column, we can parse it.
The only issue is that there's two different types of entries; ordinary text entries and deparsed vectors. So, try the following:

```
my_parse <- function(s) {
   tryCatch({ eval(parse(text=s)) }, error = function(e) { s })
}
# either
knum <- my_parse(deviceRecallsReports[row, "k_numbers"])
# or
sapply(deviceRecallsReports$k_numbers, my_parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the actual dataframe is structured, but I'm assuming it's something like this

```
library (tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
    med_device_string = c(
    "K020386",
    "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")",
    "K082829",
    "K043520",
    "c(\"K040738\", \"K061414\")",
    "K080391",
    "K991569",
    "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"
  )
) %>%
  rowid_to_column("med_device_number") 


df %>%
  mutate(med_device_string = str_remove_all(med_device_string, 'c\\(\\"|\\"\\)')) %>% 
  mutate(med_device_list = str_split(med_device_string, pattern = '\\", \\"')) %>% 
  select(-med_device_string)
```

The new column will have a list of individual strings.  You can always call `unnest` after this to get a row for each medical device submission and device code.

Comment: for (row in 1:nrow(deviceRecallsReports)) { knum <- deviceRecallsReports[row, "k_numbers"]
                   med_device_string = str_remove_all(knum, 'c\\(\\"|\\"\\)')
                   med_device_stringk = str_split(med_device_string, pattern = '\\", \\"')
                   print(paste(knum, " knum length: ", length(knum), "med_device_stringk: ", med_device_stringk))   ######## And I got the following:

Comment: [1] "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")  knum length:  1 med_device_stringk:  c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")"
Warning in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Comment: [1] "K003939  knum length:  1 med_device_stringk:  K003939"

Comment: It appears that for a single entry device number such as "K003939", it does not show me any warnings. But for a  "c(\"K032509\", \"K093308\", \"K082566\")", it is telling me argument is not an atomic vector.

Comment: You still haven't provided a minimal reproducible example of your dataset, so it's hard for me to guess how everything is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
purrr::map(deviceRecallsReports$k_numbers, ~if(grepl("^c", .x)) eval(parse(text = .x)) else .x)
```